# Workflows with google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello I'd like to know if google app script/google forms/google spreadsheet is a good way to achieve the following. (Similar to previous posts on google scripting, i am struggling a bit to understand the 'landscape' of coding problems that these google tools are good for):

1. A cohort of N players (could be hundreds) is asked to click a link to a web page where they enter a player id
2. Once the id is entered they see a message that asks them to wait until all the cohort has entered their id, and a scenario and a question (text).
3. Once everyone has entered their id players are paired at random and can answer the question by simply selecting a number from a drop down menu (e.g. 1-21)
4. The numbers given as answers are then scored according to a simple payoff matrix and each player is presented with an outcome based on the difference between the numbers they submitted as answers.
5. The game then repeats i.e. the players are asked the same question, and paired randomly again (they shouldn't need to re-enter their id)

What I want is a simple way to create this workflow/process/game, and a simple way to monitor the progress of the game. Something like a google form for the questions and answers and a google spreadsheet where the data is visible by the researchers.

What I don't know is whether app script and google forms/spreadsheets can be used to setup this process/workflow.

Forms + spreadsheets would also be neat because there are many versions of this basic game/process/workflow in economics i.e. different scoring matrices and questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in Forms, as it is not all too dynamic (not too sure), but you can easily achieve this with [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output).

You'll have to setup a linking sheet, it will store everybodys answers, and you'll constantly check this sheet for new values with [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to check periodically, and [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to retrieve the info.

Also, this platform is not the fastest or most suitable (I don't know an alternative), but it's totally doable.

Comment: For many players or faster look at appengine which will be free for your use case